# Django-google-analytics import error

Tags: python, django, google-analytics

I've installed django-google-analytics using: `env/bin/pip install django-google-analytics` with this response: `Requirement already satisfied: django-google-analytics in ./env/lib/python2.7/site-packages`.

I've added `'google_analytics',` to `INSTALLED_APPS` and I've added `GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_MODEL = True` in `settings.py`

When I run `env/bin/python manage.py syncdb` I get `ImportError: No module named google_analytics`

What do I need to do?

**EDIT**

Here's the full Traceback if helpful

```
cache cleared
cache settings imported
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/henry/Documents/culture.folder/src/culturegymnkitchen/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/henry/Documents/culture.folder/src/culturegymnkitchen/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 327, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/home/henry/Documents/culture.folder/src/culturegymnkitchen/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/henry/Documents/culture.folder/src/culturegymnkitchen/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/home/henry/Documents/culture.folder/src/culturegymnkitchen/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named google_analytics
```

Comment: what is your Django version ?

Comment: Installed from requirements.txt as Django==1.7.10

Comment: But that was the answer - I had the wrong version of something else.  I've reinstalled everything and seem to have made progress.

Comment: Cool that worked. Actually `django-google-analytics` pypi packages is messed up...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was a new package being uploaded was changing django version being used.  Once this was sorted it loaded.